# What are the complete steps to remote debug a website built in ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

I have remote debugger setup on both my client and remote machine. I'm just looking for how to use it to debug an ASP.NET website. All Google searches have failed to answer my specific question. Basically, I have open the website in Visual Studio... so where do I go from there?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369829/how-to-debug-an-asp-net-applicaiton-on-live-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has a comprehensive guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227556.aspx